# Get memberOf data for a group?

Tags: c#, active-directory

In AD how can I find what groups a group belongs to? I know that for users I can do this:

```
directoryEntry.Invoke("Groups");
```

But that doesn't work on a group.

Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ADDomain", "ADContainer");
        GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "groupName");
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = grp.GetGroups();
```